# Fetching only first element from collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to retrieve all records of Property entitiy stored as List.
This entity have collection of Photos, this collection can be filled up to 5 images.

To reduce loading time I want to retrieve list of properties and inside each property only first photo from collection. 
Since this query

```
List<Domain.Property> data = session.Query<Domain.Property>()
                       .Fetch(x => x.Photos.First())
                       .ToList();
```

gives me this error. A fetch request must be a simple member access expression; '[100002]' is a SubQueryExpression instead. Parameter name: relatedObjectSelector.

So I use

```
List<Domain.Property> data = session.Query<Domain.Property>()
                       .ToList();
```

I tried to retrieve properties in list and in foreach loop to access every property and to load photo object inside nhib. session like this

```
 var a = PropertyViewModel.FromDomainModel(data, session);

 public static List<PropertyViewModel> FromDomainModel(IList<Property> x, ISession session)
        {
            List<PropertyViewModel> dataVm = new List<PropertyViewModel>();

            foreach (Property p in x)
            {
                Photo firstPhoto = session.Get<Photo>(p.Photos[0].Id);

                dataVm.Add(new PropertyViewModel(p, firstPhoto));
            }
            return dataVm;
        }

public PropertyViewModel(Property x, Photo y)
        {
            Id = x.Id;
            ...
            Photo = new Photo();
            Photo = y;
        }
```

This approach even it looks fine (at least for me :)) it loads according to nhib. profiler 65 entities (of which Photo identifiers are 46 load, and Property 19 identifiers).
**(It should load 19 Property ident. and 19 Photo ident. first image for every property).**

What should I do wrong here?

I'm not familiar with projections so it should be the last solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `session.Query<Domain.Property>().Fetch(x => x.Photos).First().ToList()`

Comment: #Greg Ros that would not work, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could do that without a projection (`.Select()`) call.

The reason why you get so many Photos loaded when using foreach is because you are accessing a Photos collection with `p.Photos[0]` which triggers NHibernate's Lazy Loading for the collection. All Photos are loaded from the database and then the first one will be selected with the indexer `[0]`.

The lazy load will probably be triggered here even if you are using LINQ's `.First()` method instead of indexer, since you aren't calling it on an `IQueryable` instance, but on a dynamic proxy object.

Comment: Nema na čemu... Pozdravi Broja 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship between Domain.Photo and Domain.Property then it will be easier to do the query on the Photo and eager load the Property, something like this (I haven't tested if this compiles, but it should give you the general idea):

```
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Domain.Property>().Select(x => x.Min(y => y.Photos));
List<Domain.Photo> data = session.QueryOver<Domain.Photo>()
     .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id).IsIn(subQuery)
     .Fetch(x => x.Property).Eager
     .List();
```